# ThreadException.ArrayAdapter<T>

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to display my friendlist.
I use ArrayAdapter.Android studio don't find errors in code, but my friendlist display only in logs. Why my friends list does not appear on the screen??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<User> Friends = new ArrayList<User>();
    Button autorization;
    Button together;
    public final int REQUEST_LOGIN = 1;
    Account account = new Account();
    Api api;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        autorization = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autorization);
        together = (Button) findViewById(R.id.friend);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        autorization.setOnClickListener(autorizationClick);
        together.setOnClickListener(friendClick);

        account.restore(this);
        if (account.access_token != null) {
            api = new Api(account.access_token, Constants.API_ID);
        }
    }

    public void StartLoginActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LOGIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOGIN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                account.access_token = data.getStringExtra("token");
                account.user_id = data.getLongExtra("user_id", 0);
                account.save(MainActivity.this);
                api = new Api(account.access_token, Constants.API_ID);
            }
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener autorizationClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StartLoginActivity();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener friendClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FriendList();
        }
    };

    private void FriendList() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Friends = api.getFriends(account.user_id, "first_name, last_name", null, null, null);
                    ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, Friends);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    runOnUiThread(successRunnable);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    Runnable successRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Список ваших друзей ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
 921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
 921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
 921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
  921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
 921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
  921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1952)
  921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
  921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
  921-936/standandroid.ru.vkontakte1 W/System.err﹕ at standandroid.ru.vkontakte1.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:117)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` You are setting the adapter of the listview in the background thread. Try replacing it with something like:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
} 
);
```

Comment: I add it and got error:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: The layout you're passing into the adapter must contain a TextView

Comment: In order to avoid that you nees to either pass textview or ovveride getView funcrion